# How To make LXTerminal of lubuntu 16.04 transparent?

Tags: lubuntu, transparency, lxterminal

I want to know How To make LXTerminal of lubuntu 16.04 transparent ?

Answer (score 3):

Open the LXTerminal and select Edit from the top menu and then Profile Preferences->Colors.  From that screen you can change your terminal to transparent, partially transparent, the colors, etc.

Comment: can you please post the screenshots  because I dont have this `Profile Preferences->Colors`

Comment: I think that the settings of lxterminal only provide "fake" transparency. In other words, you'll see the root window and not necessarily the window immediately below the lxterminal window. It's possible that using something like compton maybe needed for true transparency.

Comment: @DKBose i've installed compton but issue still persists.

Comment: @YaShChaudhary for me it was "rightklick" on the terminal window > then click "preferences" > then click on "background" > there you can set the "Opacity"
but for me (using i3 window manager) that was no solution, because of mentiones "fake transparency"

Answer (score 3):

First install "compton"

```
apt-get install compton
```

Then run the following command for testing:

```
compton --opacity-rule 45:'class_g *= "X-terminal-emulator"'
```

It's an opacity of 45%, change it to what you like.

Above I typed "X-terminal-emulator", but to get the string you have to type, do the following:
1.) type `xprop` enter
2.) now there should be a crosshair -> klick on your terminal
3.) search for "WM_CLASS(STRING)" 
4.) use this in 'class_g *= '...'

You can copy a basic configuration from `/usr/share/doc/compton/compton.sample.conf` or here http://duncanlock.net/blog/2013/06/07/how-to-switch-to-compton-for-beautiful-tear-free-compositing-in-xfce/ **into the file** `~/.config/compton.conf` (you must create this if not present)

To make this permanent you can put this command into your profile settings.

Answer (score 3):

After installing compton (see [eli](https://askubuntu.com/a/1020331/150318)'s answer)

Edit your ~/.config/compton.conf file to include the following line:

```
opacity-rule = ["90:class_g *= 'X-terminal-emulator'"]
```

This will make your terminal's opacity 90%.

Also add `compton` to your autostart for lubuntu in `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`